# How to integrate location map in a web site?

Tags: php

I am developing a realestate site using codeigniter.I have to implement google map for each property.
How can i make an option to locate their property on google map by each user.

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the google map library. The following tutorial is quite good.

```
http://www.in-the-attic.co.uk/2010/08/20/codeigniter-google-map-library-and-html5-geolocation/
```